# copy from one textarea to all others

Tags: javascript, html

This is my form

```
    <form id=edit method=post accept-charset=UTF-8 action=>
    <input type=hidden name=video_id[0] value=K94KNsN43BU><p>Title<br>
    <textarea rows=1 cols=40 id=title_0 name=title[0]>drugi</textarea>  
    <input type=button value=Copy onclick=copyTitle()><p>Description<br>
    <textarea rows=4 cols=40 id=desc_0 name=description[0]>drugi uiuhuih</textarea>
    <p>Tags (separated by coma)<br>
    <textarea rows=2 cols=40 id=tags_0 name=tags[0]>iko koko mooko</textarea><hr>
    <input type=hidden name=video_id[1] value=oYNIKpdTT9w><p>Title<br>
    <textarea rows=1 cols=40 id=title_1 name=title[1]>prvi oijoi</textarea>
    <p>Description<br>textarea rows=4 cols=40 id=desc_1 name=description[1]>prvi</textarea>  
  <p>Tags (separated by coma)<br><textarea rows=2 cols=40 id=tags_1 name=tags[1]>prvi, koko, youtube, impotr</textarea><hr>
    <input type=submit name=submit2 value=Submit></form>
```

what I'm trying to do is to make button that copies text from first textarea wich can be for example Title to all other Title textareas that appears on the page and their number depends on the choice of user.

This is the javascript

```
function copyTitle() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title_0").value;
    var count = document.getElementById("edit").lenght/3;
    var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
        var text = document.getElementById("title_"+i);
        text.value = title;
    }
}
```

I'm dividing form lenght by 3 because there are Title, Description and Tags textareas.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `.lenght` typo?  `their number depends on the choice of user.` how does it depend? and with is the length with respect to a element with unique ID on the page? the length of its value or what?

Comment: yes, I noticed that. But it turns out the code is not good. It counts much more than I need to. I need to get number of textareas. number depends on the checkboxes from the previous form.

Comment: Number of textareas is `document.getElementById("edit").getElementsByTagName('textarea').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A whole lot. Let's start by putting quotes around property values (like this: `id="title_0"`).

Then for why your script is failing:

It's `length` not `lenght`

You are forgetting the hidden input, the copy button and the submit button, which means you have to subtract 3 from the length before dividing it by 3 (or subtract 1 afterwards, obv.). That is, if you want to solve this problem in such an ugly manner (which, for example can't handle an extra hidden input field in the form)

Comment: yes, I guess some kind of 'foreach' through all textareas function would be nicer, but it is my first javascript function and I don't know better.

Comment: That can be done (`getElementsByTagName()`), but I don't think you want textAreas, but input fields, and that makes it a lot harder, as being a button or a hidden or a text input is not defined by being a different tag, but by a property. Also, even if that would work, it'd still be ugly.

Comment: Instead I would just suggest making a variable (e.g. `var numOfTitles`) and set its value when you make your text fields (from javascript or php, or wherever the number of fields is known).

Comment: no no, i want textareas. You see, the user choose the number of videos he wants to edit. then the php script makes form which contains elements for every video. And if he wants the same description for all videos he just has to type in the first textarea and click on button that copies text to all other textareas for Description.

Comment: I see, but still I would compare against a variable that contains the info you are after, rather than to try to deduce the same information from only partly related information.